# Angular - When signing a user out, they can't log back in unless they refresh the page

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, observable, angular6

When a user logs into my app their user data is then stored in sessionStorage for ease of access throughout the app (maybe not the best approach but that's for another question).

Component code:

```
onSubmit() {
      this.auth.tryConnect(this.tryConnectUser.email, this.tryConnectUser.password).subscribe(success => {
        if (success) {
          this.tryConnectUser = new User('', '', '', '');
          swal('Good job!', 'You are now logged in', 'success').then((result) => {
            if (result) {
              this.service.loadRecipes();
              this.router.navigate(['home']);
            }
          });
        } else {
          swal('Oops', 'Please check your credentials', 'error');
        }
      });
  }
```

Service code:

```
tryConnect(email: string, password: string): Observable<Boolean> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      // u = array de users
      this.
        usersWithId.
          subscribe(u => {
        for (const a of u) {
          if (a.email === email && a.password === password) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('connectedUser', JSON.stringify(a));
            observer.next(true);
            observer.complete();
            break;
          }
        }
        observer.next(false);
        observer.complete();
      }, error1 => console.log(error1));
    });
  }
```

When they sign out I simply delete the "connectedUser" from sessionStorage and redirect to the login page

```
logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('connectedUser');
  }
```

Now, I can't figure out why that's not working:

1. The first time I try to log in, it works (popup shows and redirects + sessionStorage variable is set)
2. Then I sign out, redirects fine (sessionStorage variable now undefined which is good)
3. Then I enter the same credentials and hit login but nothing happens (no popup/error in console)

I've tried to put breakpoints pretty much everywhere and I really can't understand.

Could it be that maybe I need to unsubscribe from the login method at some point ? Or the Observable ?

EDIT:

usersWithId is basically an `Observable<User[]>` that is returned from my Firestore database.

```
this.usersWithId = this.db.collection<User>('/users').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
        data.userID = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    }));
```

Comment: What is `this.usersWithId`?

Comment: @user184994 Oh! Sorry I will update my question.

Comment: You will need to call `.snapshotChanges` again I believe, otherwise that observable isn't going to emit another value

Comment: @user184994 Wow okay it seems to be working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I see two problems in your Angular code, which are not common practice. 1. calling subscribe inside service code and 2.  connecting to database directly from your code, instead of calling an api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [@user184994](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2780943/user184994)'s comment I simply created a function to load my users from the DB and called it in the constructor **AND** in my `tryConnect` function. Everything works now.